# Overlay Password Field in Android app with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, passwords

I have an android app created with phonegap and jquery mobile. Everything is working fine and as it should except for the password fields in my register page. When I click on the password field, I get a second overlay password box. When I start typing, both the fields are updated. How can I fix this problem ? How can I stop the overlay password field from showing?

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwlkM.jpg

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: It's possible this link help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle for the Login/Register page....

http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmanor/3Rmdm/1/

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot with the problem in the question itself. Could you look at the question again and suggest? Thanks