# jQuery mobile layout on Android using checkbox

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am running into a wall trying to use jQuery mobile's UI on Android for checkboxes.  Every time it loads up in Android, it loads up off center, but even in Eclipse, the web preview appears the way it should look (as you can see in the image below with Eclipse view on the left and emulator view on the right).  I'm also trying to fix the password field which is a textbox type=password and so far, the only solution I have found to this is using jqMobi's passwordBox.  Any advice or help on this UI would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What version of Android are you testing with?

Comment: I'm testing Android version 2.2

Comment: Can we get a fiddle to play with?

Comment: you may want to show some code to get a better solution

Comment: If you're using iscroll, the issue and solution could be [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus

Comment: You need to show some code and mention what version of jQuery, jQuery Mobile you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For the cehckbox I simply set the CSS to display none for the checkbox so Android knows not to draw anything and let jQuery mobile still create the button for me.  Works better now.