# Text box automatically scrolls for Phonegap app in HTC sensation device

Tags: android, cordova

We are implementing Phonegap app for Android devices. In one of our screens we have text box, on focus of text box in landscape mode of device , screen scrolls automatically up and down continuously and this issue we are getting only in HTC sensation device.

Issue is not occuring in portarit mode of device.

Please assist me to resolve issue.

Comment: Show some code as we cant imagine why it is happening

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus