# Phonegap keyboard scrolls the page up and down on focused input

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, keyboard, scroll

When using a jQuery Mobile dialog with an focused input field, the page continuously scrolls up and down because of the keyboard that appears. This is on a rather small phone (HTC Explorer), but the problem does not exist in larger phones such as a HTC Sensation.

When removing the keyboard from the screen, the problem disappears.

Does anyone know any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same issue discussed 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus

Answer (score 2):

I got around this basically by immediately scrolling the page back to the top:

```
$('#myInput').bind('focus',function(event){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the [official](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) documentation for more info.