# show password field value for a moment in phone gap android application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, passwords

How is it possible to display the input text as it is instead of star for a moment in a password field in a JQM android phonegap application. (This is working in android 4.1 but not in android 2.2)

Thnx

Comment: Click [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus

i think this link is used full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is platform specific. Just checked few apps in my android 2.3 v mobile and there was no character display , when you press it.

I recommend not to go for it. Still some possible solutions would be ( if you are too much bothered about it)

1. Create an event and show the pressed character for a second using javascript ( but you will have to check the platform and disable this when the app is in 4.1/ other higher versions as there is already a display there)
2. put an option "show password" ,and show the whole password. ( Standard approach )