# Misplacing Text field when div is Scrolling

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have developed the android phonegap using jquery and javascript.I have a div with scrollbar(with many textboxes).In the onfocus of textbox i need to scroll the div to top position so that the focused textbox move to top position of div.

Here is my code:

```
$('input:text').live('focus', function() 
{
    var container = $(this);
   container.scrollTop(0);

});
```

Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you facing the problem that input field is hiding back to key board and what to show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the below line in manifest in Application Tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: Thanks...I already have this line in manifest file.But sometimes when i type in the fourth textbox,it automatically types in fifth textbox because of small devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906956/phonegap-input-type-password-field-focus __ is this type of issue

Comment: is your device htc ? then try in emulator.. ya there is web view scrolling issue in android..

Comment: My device is sony ericsson live walkman(android 4.0.4).I have tried in emulator and also in galaxy notebook.I didnt face this issue.Previously sony ericsson is in android 2.3,and at that time i didnt face this issue...

Comment: it is not due to device size, it may be due to version plz check in 4.1 emulator. in iScroll i to faced this problem , Is your in field type Password ? - thank you, all the best

Comment: I am facing this problem in emulator and dont have android 4.1 device.All my field type is text.But i didnt face this problem in galaxy notebook(android 4.0-large devices).